# JVM arguments while starting tomcat in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, tomcat8, jvm-arguments

I am using "Tomcat for Java" plugin in my Visual Studio Code for starting and stopping tomcat server.
This plugin provide following options
1. "jvm.option" to specify JVM arguments
2. "server.xml" to specify tomcat server.xml configuration.
I want to pass some additional environment variables like below while starting tomcat. I could pass additional JVM arguments in STS/Eclipse by double clicking tomcat.
Can someone help me how I could pass below environment variable in VSCode.

```
-Dconfig=/x/app/config/production.conf 
-DlogbackFile=x/app/config/logback.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

After adding tomcat to your VS code, you can right click on the tomcat and select 'Customize JVM Options'.

After it is open, you can add the parameters that you add in VM arguements in eclipse in here.

[image: JVM option in VS code tomcat]